# Where to put a Map on the Contact Us page?

Tags: website-design, forms, user-expectation, layout

I’m working on a Contact Us page and trying to keep it minimal with only 3 sections (in order):

1. Map
2. Contact Us Form
3. Footer

Does it matter if it is:

1. Contact Us Form
2. Map
3. Footer?

Edit:
I have removed the address from the footer of each page to moved it to the header (the header overlays on the entire page - it has links to other pages and some contact information, so I added the address there).
The header - with some rearranges - maintains all the information on the mobile as well.

The client is an interior decorator - expecting people to visit.

Mobile view of the header:
[image]

The first deleted text is the address and then next is the email, and below that are the phone numbers.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this might cause problems?

Comment: Not exactly. What would you prefer? @maxathousand

Comment: I've seen it done in various ways, but as long as the important information is easily accessible, I don't really see any "right" or "wrong" way to go.

Comment: Okay, thanks. @maxathousand

Comment: You probably want to put this near where the address information is provided?

Comment: It would be easier to answer with more context. Is the business a physical one that is visited by customers in person. Then the address is important, else contacting might be rather digital.

Comment: @greenforest we are expecting visits from customers

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to this issue, I usually recommend two solutions. Make sure to test them both:

1. Two column grid, left column contains the address, telephone number, form, email, hours etc. Second column contains the map.
2. Make the app cover the entire section right before the footer so the users can see more of it and this way it will be easier for them to identify your location because there will be more reference points exposed.

Comment: My preferred way too. And when you think about responsiveness, the result on a small screen is that contact info precedes map, implicitly answering that part of the question.